# unable to get user email from payPal response (SDk rest api) in laravel after approved

Tags: laravel

I am going to integrate paypal in laravel! according to this

```
[http://www.17educations.com/laravel/paypal-integration-in-laravel/#disqus_thread][1]
```

Its work fine redirect paypal and verified and transation is done successfull 
its ok and  got response: as follow:
now how to get Email etc. from this response?

```
PayPal\Api\Payment Object
(
    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => PAY-6F912481CR395364MK5L5QFI
            [intent] => sale
            [state] => approved
            [cart] => 4UA93426DX9093236
            [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object
                (
                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                        (
                            [payment_method] => paypal
                            [payer_info] => PayPal\Api\PayerInfo Object
                                (
                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [email] => aassuamba99@gmail.com
                                            [first_name] => Amba
                                            [last_name] => Joshi
                                            [payer_id] => 9B8FFYJJZEHM6
                                            [shipping_address] => PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress Object
                                                (
                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [recipient_name] => Amba Joshi
                                                            [line1] => Flat no. 507 Wing A Raheja Residency
                                                            [line2] => Film City Road, Goregaon East
                                                            [city] => Mumbai
                                                            [state] => Maharashtra
                                                            [postal_code] => 400097
                                                            [country_code] => IN
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [country_code] => IN
                                            [billing_address] => PayPal\Api\Address Object
                                                (
                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [line1] => Flat no. 507 Wing A Raheja Residency
                                                            [line2] => Film City Road, Goregaon East
                                                            [city] => Mumbai
                                                            [state] => Maharashtra
                                                            [postal_code] => 400097
                                                            [country_code] => IN
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [transactions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object
                        (
                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object
                                        (
                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [total] => 50.00
                                                    [currency] => USD
                                                    [details] => PayPal\Api\Details Object
                                                        (
                                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [description] => Your transaction description
                                    [item_list] => PayPal\Api\ItemList Object
                                        (
                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [items] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [name] => HEAD, NECK AND SHOULDER INC. MINI FACIAL MASSAGE
                                                                            [price] => 50.00
                                                                            [currency] => USD
                                                                            [quantity] => 1
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [shipping_address] => PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress Object
                                                        (
                                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [recipient_name] => Amba Joshi
                                                                    [line1] => Flat no. 507 Wing A Raheja Residency
                                                                    [line2] => Film City Road, Goregaon East
                                                                    [city] => Mumbai
                                                                    [state] => Maharashtra
                                                                    [postal_code] => 400097
                                                                    [country_code] => IN
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [related_resources] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => PayPal\Api\RelatedResources Object
                                                (
                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [sale] => PayPal\Api\Sale Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 0W808156RU066263U
                                                                            [state] => completed
                                                                            [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [total] => 50.00
                                                                                            [currency] => USD
                                                                                            [details] => PayPal\Api\Details Object
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                                                        (
                                                                                                        )

                                                                                                )

                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [payment_mode] => INSTANT_TRANSFER
                                                                            [protection_eligibility] => ELIGIBLE
                                                                            [protection_eligibility_type] => ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE
                                                                            [transaction_fee] => PayPal\Api\Currency Object
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [value] => 2.25
                                                                                            [currency] => USD
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [parent_payment] => PAY-6F912481CR395364MK5L5QFI
                                                                            [create_time] => 2016-06-08T08:32:59Z
                                                                            [update_time] => 2016-06-08T08:32:59Z
                                                                            [links] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/0W808156RU066263U
                                                                                                    [rel] => self
                                                                                                    [method] => GET
                                                                                                )

                                                                                        )

                                                                                    [1] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/0W808156RU066263U/refund
                                                                                                    [rel] => refund
                                                                                                    [method] => POST
                                                                                                )

                                                                                        )

                                                                                    [2] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6F912481CR395364MK5L5QFI
                                                                                                    [rel] => parent_payment
                                                                                                    [method] => GET
                                                                                                )

                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [soft_descriptor] => PAYPAL *TESTFACILIT
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [redirect_urls] => PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls Object
                (
                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                        (
                            [return_url] => http://localhost/massagess/payment/status?paymentId=PAY-6F912481CR395364MK5L5QFI
                            [cancel_url] => http://localhost/massagess/payment/status
                        )

                )

            [create_time] => 2016-06-08T08:33:00Z
            [update_time] => 2016-06-08T08:32:55Z
            [links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                        (
                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6F912481CR395364MK5L5QFI
                                    [rel] => self
                                    [method] => GET
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this methods, preferably i think `getPayer()` is what u need:

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Payment.html